# I need to grayed a cell out depending on user input using vba

Tags: vba, excel

So I have this list of information I need the user to submit so that it can be included in a different sheet.(see pic below) I want this code to gray out a row if another is picked. So if the user inputs a "starting" time, then I want the row with "dependency" to gray out, and the user won't be able to use it. IF the user clicks "dependency" then the "starting time" needs to gray out. Here is my current code.

[image]

```
Sub findData()
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim workflows As String

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        workflows = .Range("C5").Value
        servergri = .Range("C9").Value
        gridf = .Range("C9").Value
        StartTime = .Range("c11").Value
    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet3")
        finalrow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 5 To finalrow
            If .Cells(i, 3) = workflows And (.Cells(i, 4) = servergri Or .Cells(i, 5) = gridf) Then

                .Rows(i).Insert
                'Add new information to the new row.
                'The new row number is still = i

                .Cells(i, 3) = workflows
                .Cells(i, 4) = servergri
                .Cells(i, 6) = StartTime
                    .Cells(i, 3).Resize(2, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 8



                'If you only want to add one row then your should exit the loop
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c9").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: You can `worksheet_change` event and then `interior.color` to change fill of cell, then `protect worksheet` and `lock the cell` so user cannot edit. It's also best to post the code you've actually tried to accomplish your goal. Most people aren't too wiling to code from scratch on this site.

Comment: This looks like it might be better suited to a UserForm.